# left join two tables where my variable is less than 5

Tags: mysql, sql

Im creating a query that select two tables and create a total variable by count a field in one table.
Example:

```
 Table A:

 ID   |  email
 1    |  test@test
 2    |  test2@test
 3    |  test3@test
```

Table B

```
ID | email_id  | username_id
 1  |  1        | 11
 2  |  1        | 22
 3  |  2        | 33
```

My query:

```
select a.id, a.email, count(c.id) as total
from tableA a
left join tableC c on c.email_id = a.id AND total <= 5
group by a.email LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
 Unknown column 'total' in 'on clause
```

I need to select the first "a.id" that has total <= 5. How can I do it?

Comment: Total is an expression alias, you can just use the expression itself `and count(c.id) < 5`, unless of course you meant to do this in the where clause instead which will operate across the join result, but with a grouping you want to do it using a `having`.

Comment: What is `LIMIT 1`for? To arbitrarily pick one email and show it?

Comment: And there is a unique constraint on tableA.email, I guess?

Comment: Yes, I need just one email to showw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically `Select` is processed after the `Where` clause so you cannot use Alias name in same `Where` clause.

Use `HAVING` clause

```
select a.id, a.email, count(c.id) as total
from tableA a
left join tableC c on c.email_id = a.id 
group by a.email 
Having count(c.id) <= 5
LIMIT 1
```

I think `Mysql` allows you do this as well

```
Having total <= 5
```

Comment: beat me to it by 2 seconds! +1

Comment: Not entirely sure but this might make the join essentially inner instead of left and exclude any emails that don't have a record in table B from the results.

Comment: @Anand - No.. In that case `Count` will be `zero` and we are checking for `count <= 5` .  You are confused between filtering data in `Where` clause and `Having` clause.

Comment: @Prdp, ok thanks, I wasn't sure about it because I didn't test it but my thought was that count might be ```NULL``` instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try HAVING Count(c.id) <= 5

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this a bit clearer, since the correct answer has already been provided - You don't have to use the `HAVING` clause, and the `HAVING` clause is not always the solution for this problem.

The `HAVING` clause is usually used to place filters on aggregated columns (sum,count,max,min etc..) , but when you have a calculated column (`colA + colB as calc_column` for example) , then another approach , which should work here as well is to wrap the query with another select, and then the new column will be available on the `WHERE` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (The query here ) s
WHERE s.total <= 5
```